# Google cloud shell with ?authuser=1 parameter keeps loading

Tags: google-cloud-shell

I use 2 google accounts on my Chromebook and I really like to use google cloud shell, however when I try to log in on my second account, it loads for around 5 minutes and the finally says that "google cloud shell is temporarily unavailable". Using my primary account works fine. If anyone has any tips those would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you are hitting a product bug.  Could you please submit in-product feedback (under the ... menu in the right corner) when you are trying log in with the failing user and the team will investigate.